# Japanese characters interpreted as control character

Tags: parsing, encoding, utf-8

I have several files which include various strings in different written languages. The files I am working with are in the .inf format which is somewhat similar to .ini files.

I am inputting the text from these files into a parser which considers the `[` symbol as the beginning of a 'category'. Therefore, it is important that this character does not accidentally appear in string sequences or parsing will fail because it interprets these as "control characters".

For example, this string contains some Japanese writings:

```
iANSProtocol_HELP="�C���e��(R) �A�h�o���X�g�E�l�b�g���[�N�E�T�[�r�X Protocol �̓`�[���������щ��z LAN �Ȃǂ̍��x�@�\�Ɏg�����܂��B"
DISKNAME         ="�C���e��(R) �A�h�o���X�g�E�l�b�g���[�N�E�T�[�r�X CD-ROM �܂��̓t���b�s�[�f�B�X�N"
```

In my text-editors (Atom) default UTF-8 encoding this gives me garbage text which would not be an issue, however the `0x5B` character is interpreted as `[`. Which causes the parser to fail because it assumes that this is signaling the beginning of a new category.

If I change the encoding to Japanese (CP 932), these characters are interpreted correctly as:

```
iANSProtocol_HELP="インテル(R) アドバンスト・ネットワーク・サービス Protocol はチーム化および仮想 LAN などの高度機能に使われます。"
DISKNAME         ="インテル(R) アドバンスト・ネットワーク・サービス CD-ROM またはフロッピーディスク"
```

Of course I cannot encode every file to be Japanese because they may contain Chinese or other languages which will be written incorrectly.

What is the best course of action for this situation? Should I edit the code of the parser to escape characters inside string literals? Are there any special types of encoding that would allow me to see all special characters and languages?

Thanks

Comment: The program has to be told the character encoding used to write the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the source file is in shift-jis, then you should use a parser that can support it, or convert the file to UTF-8 before you parse it.

I believe that this character set also uses ASCII as it's base type but it uses 2 bytes to for certain characters, so if `0x5B` it probably doesn't appear as the 'first byte' of a character. (note: this is conjecture based on how I *think* shift-jis works).

So yea, you need to modify your parser to understand shift-jis, or you need to convert the file to UTF-8 before parsing. I imagine that converting is the easiest.